# SpriteWidget: App doesn't response to handleEvent in NodeWithSize

Tags: dart, flutter

I created a widget, added some Sprites and made some animation. I want to add some user interaction but `handelEvent` method is not working. I already set `userInteractionEnabled` to `true`.

I tried debugging and place a breakpoint inside the `handleEvent` method but it didn't stop when I touched the screen.

```
class MainSceneBackgroundNode extends NodeWithSize {
    Sprite _logo;
    RepeatedImage _background;
    GuyImage _guy;
    int _i = 0;
    int _j = 0;

    int _dir = -1;

    MainSceneBackgroundNode() : super(new Size(2560.0, 1440.0)) {
        userInteractionEnabled = true;
        handleMultiplePointers = false;

        // Add background
        _background = new RepeatedImage(_imageMap["assets/background.png"]);
        addChild(_background);

        _guy = new GuyImage();
        addChild(_guy);

        _logo = new Sprite.fromImage(_imageMap["assets/logo.gif"]);
        _logo.pivot = Offset.zero;
        _logo.size = new Size(912, 486);
        _logo.position = new Offset(824, 10);
        addChild(_logo);
    }

    @override
    bool handleEvent(SpriteBoxEvent event) {
        if (event.type == PointerDownEvent) {
            if (event.boxPosition.dx < 1280) {
                _dir = -1;
            } else {
                _dir = 1;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }     
...        
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. I don't know what else to do.

Thanks in Advance.